# Calling a Method from a different Class - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to call the method "foo" which is in the class called "fooClass". In another class i have my appDelegate and I want to execute the method foo in applicationdidfinishlaunching. I have imported the class "fooClass" into the appDelegate header file and I did initiate it in applicationdidfinishlaunching with this:

"fooClass *blah = [[fooClass alloc]init];"

Then running the method by doing this:

"[blah foo];"

However when I debug and launch the program the stuff in foo method is not being executed. Can anyone help me out on this issue?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Check `blah` variable right before you call `foo` method. Is it initialized?

Comment: Yes I believe it is because I have "fooClass *blah = [[fooClass alloc] init];"

Comment: There's not really much to it because I'm just trying to test this out. In the foo method there is only "NSlog(@"working"$;" to see I'd the method is being called. Other than that there's just the standard code for a window based app.

Comment: The question is: what is between alloc and foo. Are they in the same function? Is *blah just internal variable or property? If you're trying to get help - please provide more information.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob at this objective c. Here is the source code if that will help solve the problem. http://www.mediafire.com/?5cs439r4cj2jrc2